# Match string only when not preceded by another string

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match strings containing `MYSTUFF` in all cases, *except* when `MYSTUFF` is preceded by `ENABLED_`. So that the following would match:

- `MYSTUFF`
- `m_MYSTUFF`
- `MYSTUFFIsGreat`
- `allOf_MYSTUFF`

but the following wouldn't:

- `ENABLED_MYSTUFF`
- `m_ENABLED_MYSTUFF`
- `ENABLED_MYSTUFFIsGreat`
- `allOf_ENABLED_MYSTUFF`

I tried several variations using negative lookahead (variations of `\w*(?!.*ENABLED_)MYSTUFF\w*`), and conditional (variations of `(?(?!=ENABLED_)(MYSTUFF))`), but I did not manage to get the results I'm after.

Is what I want even doable with regexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) assertion ...

```
\w*(?<!ENABLED_)MYSTUFF\w*
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC1wGz/1)**

Comment: I do want to match the whole word.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear I need the whole word.